# it's not possible to loop .click function (To create multiple buttons)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, each

I'm trying to create multiple buttons that each one of them doing something. It is working great outside of the `each` loop, but the moment I insert the `click` function in the `each` function, it doesn't work.

```
$.each(data.arr, function(i, s){
    html += '<div id="mybtn'+s.id+'"><button class="first">Btn1</button><button class="second">Btn2</button></div>';

    var btnclass="#mybtn"+s.id+" .first";

    $(btnclass).click(function(){
      //do something 
    });
});
```

Please let me know what is wrong...

**Thank you very much!!!**

Eran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data.arr, function(i, s){
  html += '<div id="mybtn'+s.id+'"><button class="first">Btn1</button><button   class="second">Btn2</button></div>';
  var btnclass="#mybtn"+Id+" .first";
  $(btnclass).click(function(){
    //do something });
  });
});
```

1. you assign the event to the `<div>`, not the button
2. this also fails, since you not have an "Id"
3. never adds the HTML to anything = no events either way

"right" way (guessing intention) :

```
$.each(data.arr, function(i, s){
  var html = '<div id="mydiv'+s.id+'">';
  html += '<button id="mybtn1'+s.id+'" class="first clickbtn">Btn1</button>';
  html += '<button id="mybtn2'+s.id+'" class="second clickbtn">Btn2</button>';
  html += '</div>';

  $(someElement).append(html);

  $(".clickbtn").on('click', function(){
     //do something });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the issue! I simply doesn't finish the HTML code, and i called the click function before...

Comment: To fix it: Simply call the Click function later on (Or run another .each function with the .click function after you finish the HTML code).. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Missing space between the id selector and class

```
var btnclass="#mybtn"+s.id " +  .first";
                          ^ 
                        Space here .. And the 
     + sign should come after the string
```

Also try moving the click event outside the for loop and delegate it...

```
$.each(data.arr, function(i, s){
    html += '<div id="mybtn'+s.id+'"><button class="first">Btn1</button><button class="second">Btn2</button></div>';

});

 $('body').on('click', '.first' , function(){
      //do something 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

> var btnclass="#mybtn"+Id+" .first";

should be

> var btnclass="#mybtn"+s.id+" .first";

?

Also, you need to attach the contents of your html variable to the DOM, so the click event can find it.